# after upgrading angular 4 to 7 store is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

i have upgraded my app from angular 4 to 7
i am facing problem with my ngrx Store module. it was working fine with Angular 4 but now when i upgraded to latest 7 it is giving me error in entire app.
saying

**Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type Store< any >.**

this is how i am accessing

```
   this.store
  .select("codeSelectionSession")
  .subscribe((session: TestOrderCodeSelectionSession) => {
    // checks for null and undefined
    if (session == null) {
      this.store.select("testOrder").subscribe((testOrder: TestOrder) => {
        this.codeSelectionSession = new TestOrderCodeSelectionSession();
        this.store.dispatch(
          new SetTestOrderCodeSelectionSession(this.codeSelectionSession)
        );
      });
    } else {
      this.codeSelectionSession = session;
    }
  });
```

and

```
 this.store
  .select("patient")
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.patient = Object.assign({}, this.patient, data);
  });
```

select and subscribe is giving error

my store version is

```
"@ngrx/store": "4.1.1",
```

does someone know how to resolve this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your @ngrx/store and other dependency to version 7 also like

```
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
```